# Preventing execution of stored procedure when debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Every time when I use debugger, one of my stored procedures is executed, even when I stop the debugger before reaching the line of code responsible for saving data to the database.

How could I prevent this from happening? I don't want to have incomplete rows in the database.

```
POrder po = new POrder();          
po.PODate = DateTime.Parse(txtPODate.Text);  <-- Breakpoint here

po.POVendorID = int.Parse(ddPOVendors.SelectedValue);  <-- Stop Debugging here
```

I am not reaching `po.AddNewOrder` yet and I stop the debugger, so I am not executing the stored procedure yet

```
po.AddNewOrder();
```

`POrder` class:

```
    public DateTime  PODate { get; set; }
    public int POVendorID { get; set; }

    public void AddNewOrder()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ss.GetConectionString());

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspAddNewPOrder", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter parPODate = new SqlParameter("@PODate", SqlDbType.Date);
        parPODate.Value = PODate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parPODate);

        SqlParameter parPOVendorID = new SqlParameter("@POVendorID", SqlDbType.Int);
        parPOVendorID.Value = POVendorID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parPOVendorID);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception exp) 
        {
            throw new Exception(exp.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspAddNewPOrder] 
(
        @PODate datetime = null,
        @POVendorID int= null
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PurchaseOrders.[dbo].[tblPurchaseOrders]
    (
       PODate,
       POVendorID

    )
    VALUES
    (
       @PODate,
       @POVendorID
    )
END
```

Comment: Wrap the call in a transaction?

Comment: What's probably happening is that you're leaving your browser open along with the `ASP.NET Development Server`, and even though you stopped debugging your browser completes it's request.

Comment: @Bob Vale Thanks, How I could do that?

Comment: There's a difference between ceasing to run the debugger (by hitting F5 or detatching your debugger) and actually terminating the session you're debugging.  You would have to end the server process in order to prevent the request from completing and the rest of the code executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preprocessor directives` to skip a sections of code executing given a condition (ex; during debugging in your case). Have a look at this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
#define DEBUG
public class YourClass 
{
    POrder po = new POrder();          
    po.PODate = DateTime.Parse(txtPODate.Text);
    Break point here ->

    po.POVendorID = int.Parse(ddPOVendors.SelectedValue);
    #if (!DEBUG)
        po.AddNewOrder(); //this will not be executed during debug.
    #endif
    ....      
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he's asking for... he's saying that when he's debugging, he'll run across a problem and stop his debugger before the call to `po.AddNewOrder()`, but that line is still executed. I think he wants it to execute when debugging if he allows it to reach the line.

Comment: @Kaf thanks this is helpfull and it would solve the problem, but I em testing for different users behavior and actualy in some point I would like to use this line and to be executed.